# What is the function of じゃ at the end of this sentence

Tags: particle-は

I know the meaning of the whole sentence but what is the function and meaning of じゃ at the end of the sentence:

> お巡りさんには関係ありません じゃ

I checked on the internet and maybe じゃ means "I guess".

Comment: Is there any further context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further context, it should be a contracted じゃあ　([じゃ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%98%E3%82%83/#jn-101354) #2), meaning *bye*. It is a way to end the conversation.

Comment: yes you are right it means bye.